# Can MathJax render a LaTeX math expression as an image?

Tags: api, latex, mathjax

I know that **[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)** can render LaTeX mathematical expressions as text.

Can MathJax render LaTeX math expressions as images? I can't find any information about this in the help documentation. If so, could you tell me the details? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're asking whether MathJax can *render* math expression as images. Unfortunately, the answer is no: the only output formats are HTML-with-CSS and MathML, [according to the documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/output.html). Of course, you could try to convert the resulting HTML+CSS to an image using some other method/library.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure MathJax to produce output using SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) by:
TeX-AMS-MML_SVG.js

refer to the following link for more information:

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-a-configuration-file

Comment: linked page does not exist.