# how to convert MathJax formula to img

Tags: javascript, html, image, mathjax

Mathjax now is working well in my project. but there is one problem. is there any way to convert MathJax's formula(pure html and css) into a img file. that I can save.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can MathJax render a LaTeX math expression as an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517296/can-mathjax-render-a-latex-math-expression-as-an-image)

Comment: For KaTeX lovers, track https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/375 (no image output as of now)

Comment: If you just want an individual screenshot (rather than an automatic process that happens every time), in Firefox you can select the element in developer tools, right-click on the element in the source inspector, and select "Screenshot Node".

Answer (score 10):

MathJax can be configured to produce an SVG.  See http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html about the portability.

There is now an easy solution to produce SVG with mathjax on a server: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node
For PNG see:
https://github.com/pkra/mathjax-node-svg2png

Comment: PNG generation was removed from MathJax-Node. See https://github.com/pkra/mathjax-node-svg2png instead.

Answer (score -5):

Obviously Mathjax wasn't made for that.

If it's just for a few equations, use a screenshot utility tool that allows you to quickly select the area you want and save it to an image.

If it's for batch work, install the real LaTeX and ImageMagick on your server to generate the images. But it's contrary to the spirit of the lightweight system that Mathjax provides and the rendering won't be the same.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/how-to-export-a-equation-as-a-image-without-background

Comment: Yeah, i'm downloading MacTex right now and you know it takes 3.2 GiB to download is using an intrusive setup package and the installer might crash and force you to reboot. All just because someone what a math formular that could be layouted in 100KiB code?  That makes sense.

Comment: Dude, my answer was from 2013. They obviously updated the library.

Comment: The downvote was not for your comment about what the library was made for. It was because you suggested to use a gigabyte large Latex environment instead. This is the advice that now makes modern software so terrible bloated (aka the use of the electron framework)

Comment: What about Docker haha